# azure-pipelines.yaml: Cannot authenticate organization scoped feed

Tags: npm, azure-devops

I'm having a .npmrc file:

```
registry=https://XXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YYY/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
```

And my azure-pipelines.yaml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
  displayName: 'npm install'
```

My feed has 'Project Collection Build Service' as 'Contributor'.

However I keep getting this:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.19.0/x64/bin/npm install
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://XXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YYY/npm/registry/ansi-regex - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
npm ERR! 403 
npm ERR! 403 It was specified as a dependency of 's'
npm ERR! 403
```

Comment: Try rerunning the pipeline again. It fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My feed has 'Project Collection Build Service' as 'Contributor'.

As normal, this is not a general solution, it only available while the **service account** that the pipeline used is `Project Collection Build Service`. `Project Collection Build Service` is a organization-level build service account

I'm afraid your pipeline here is using `project-level build service account`.

---

Here has 2 method you can consider to use.

**Method 1**:

Please go `Feed settings` => `Permissions`, add your project-level build service account and assign it `Contributor` role. Its account name should like `{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})`.

Re-run your pipeline to see whether it can run successfully.

**Method 2**:

Go Project settings => Settings, and make sure `Limit job authorization scope to current project` is disabled:

[image]

Only it disabled, the service account that pipeline used is collection-level one. At this time, your original permission configuration would be available now.

---

*At last, which is not what I expected, is you are facing our [event](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/181290885). Not sure, but hoping you are just facing permission issue.*