# Azure Artifacts - Universal Packages - Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to push the package

Tags: azure-devops

Devops folks,

I am pushing the build pipeline output to Azure Artefacts - Universal packages for a full stack .net application. The application builds successfully and produces an output in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

Would like to publish all these build outputs to UniversalPackages and let release pipeline take it over from there.

I have checked for below things:

**1.** Permission - Project Collection Build Service - Contributor Role.

**2.** Task Configuration Confirmed below "UniversalPackages"

```
 - task: UniversalPackages@0
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg'
      feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
      vstsFeedPublish: '123456fg-test-1234-1234-31161a66dc4d/b92b3313-ab41-4044-test-e94146618efb'
      vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'Text here-Services-Package'
      versionOption: 'minor'
      packagePublishDescription: 'Contains some text here)'
      verbosity: 'Trace'
```

sorry for YAML indenting issues,

Below is the pipeline log

```
2020-04-04T02:36:03.9835393Z Publishing package: test, version: 0.0.1 using feed id: 76a3991f-e6fc-767b-a0dc-90e38c54e558, project: 7813b7e3-bbf1-4355-9263-31161a66dc4d 

2020-04-04T02:36:04.0147395Z [command]D:\ABCAgent\_work\_tool\artifacttool\0.2.151\x64\ArtifactTool.exe universal publish --feed 76a3991f-e6fc-767b-a0dc-90e38c54e558 --service https://dev.azure.com/QWERTY/ --package-name test --package-version 0.0.1 --path D:\AzureAgentBuild\_work\1\a --patvar UNIVERSAL_PUBLISH_PAT --verbosity None --description "" --project 7813b7e3-bbf1-4355-9263-31161a66dc4d 

2020-04-04T02:36:09.2875733Z {"@t":"2020-04-04T02:36:08.7883701Z","@m":"[GetDedupManifestArtifactClientAsync] Try 1/5, non-retryable exception caught. Throwing. Details:\r\nNo LastRequestResponse on exception VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden","@i":"b2d31574","@l":"Warning","@x":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden\r\n ​
```

Comment: May I know what’s the status of this before the weekend?

Comment: G'day, @merlin mate, Easter holidays, I will check it next week and keep you posted. thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException:
>   Forbidden

This permission error can be converted as 403 error code, which means the account does not have enough operation permission to publish package to universal package.

You said you had assign 'Project Collection Build Service' with 'Contributor' role. BUT, this is not a solution for all scenario. It only available while the build pipeline is using 'Project Collection Build Service' account, a **collection level** service account. There still has another scenario, the pipeline may using **project-level** service account.

---

*You can with the methods I shared in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844464/azure-pipelines-yaml-cannot-authenticate-organization-scoped-feed/60860032#60860032). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156304/11508165) to get another similar issue and explanation.*

**Method 1**:

Please go `Feed settings` => `Permissions`, add your project-level build service account and assign it `Contributor` role. Its account name should like `{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})`.

Re-run your pipeline to see whether it can run successfully.

**Method 2**:

Go Project settings => Settings, and make sure `Limit job authorization scope to current project` is disabled:

[image]

Only it disabled, the service account that pipeline used is collection-level one. At this time, your original permission configuration would be available now.

Comment: Tried both the methods, no success. Looks like a network firewall issue? forbidden error at my end..

Comment: @VarunMaggo, What about try with using Hosted agent to verify? This can prove whether it is a permission lack issue, or caused by your firewall.

Comment: Just got it fixed, the forbidden error was due to the proxy being blocked at the on-prem server. We removed the proxy and routed all the data via Azure Express Route. Problem Solved.

Comment: To clarify the reason for Method 1 and 2 is because of how you created the Feed.  Organization (Method 2) or Project (Method 1)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with permission for pipelines build service, the root cause was found to be with proxy being blocking the universal package with a forbidden error.

We just removed the proxy from the on-prem, self-hosted build agent and used Azure Express Route to route the traffic. This simple change fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can doublecheck in the Billing options if the Artifact free space is used up. I fixed it using this option.

[image]